# Network Disabled

Tags: wireless, networking

I recently bought a dell laptop with Ubuntu preinstalled in it. The wifi was working fine then, after a week or so i updated ubuntu. From that time i am not able to use net over WIFI. I did try few commands like sudo rfkill all, rfkill unblock all, rfkill unblock wifi. I did not get any results. I am new to this OS please help me out.

Comment: Please open a terminal, type the command `lspci -vnn | grep Network` and copy-paste the output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Driver problem. Uninstall the driver and again install the wifi driver. It will solve your problem.

Like this you have to do,

First you have to remove the bcmwl kernel source:

```
     sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then again install :

```
     sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```